# Try - Except python

Tags: python

I am currently trying to parse an HTML page. While doing so, I have to perform

1. Search a specific string and do some steps. (if this operation fails, go to step b)
2. Search a specific string using a different code and do some steps.  (if this operation fails, go to step 3)
3. Search a specific string using a different code and do some steps.

I am doing like this and my question is if I have to try multiple times, how to specify try and except.

```
try:   
    #step 1 

except: #   ( not sure what kind of error will execute step2) 
    #step 2

except:
    #step 3
```

thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to nest try/except blocks?

Comment: Yes, what *is* your question?

Comment: Why not use use Python standard HTML parsers?

Answer (score 8):

The structure would be

```
try:
    step 1
except:
    try:
        step 2
    except:
        step 3
```

Two notes:

First, although using exceptions is a very "pythonic" way to accomplish tasks, you should check, if you couldn't use a nested `if`/`elif`/`else` structure.

Second, there is a [HTML Parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) right in the Python standard library. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782097) also has some HTML to DOM Parsers in the answers (i.e. Parsers that construct a DOM structure out of the HTML document, if that makes your task easier). You should be very sure that you *don't* want to use an existing solution before writing your own :) ...

Answer (score 4):

I agree with BlackVegetable that this could probably be done with a simple if/elif, but if you have a specific reason to want to use exceptions, you can do something like this:

```
for method in (method1, method2, method3):
    try:
        return method(parameter)
    except VerySpecificException as _:
        pass
```

as a more complete example:

```
def method1(param):
    raise Exception('Exception: method 1 broke')

def method2(param):
    raise Exception('Exception: method 2 broke')

def method3(param):
    print param

def main():
    param = 'success!'
    for method in (method1, method2, method3):
        try:
            return method(param)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

prints:

```
Exception: method 1 broke
Exception: method 2 broke
success!
```

If either of the first methods does not break, then those methods will return success and the loop will end.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it might be best served by using if/elif:

```
if conditionA:
    # do something
elif conditionB:
    # do something else
elif conditionC:
    # do something completely different
else:
    # go cry in a room
```