# Using reg ex with html scraping

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

In my html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p> simple text <br>
next text sample <br>
end of para .. </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Using python reg ex I want to know how can I :

```
list= ['text' , 'sample' ]
#read each line and find the word from the list
# 
# then check whether the word is succeeded by a br tag
#
#
```

Can any one please share their suggestions?

Comment: [Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) Here are some recommended [DOM parsers for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2782097/87399).

Comment: thanks for the reply!! If I want to do this using beautifulsoup , how shld i go about it?