# How to regex for entry between quotes?

Tags: python, regex

I need to get the entries between the quotes like in this example: Regex `href="x....dkjads...href="y"` and it returns `x` and `y`.

`[<a class="lightbox" href="fileadmin/user_upload/images/Sprachen/Englisch/USA/San_Diego/San_Diego_EC/EC_San_Diego_Galerie.jpg" title=""><img alt="Sprachschule EC San Diego" border="0" height="80" src="typo3temp/pics/EC_San_Diego_Galerie_d1def1bf4a.jpg" title="Sprachschule EC San Diego (Copyright EC San Diego. All rights reserved.)" width="80"/></a>, <a class="lightbox" href="fileadmin/user_upload/images/Sprachen/Englisch/USA/San_Diego/San_Diego_EC/EC_San_Diego_Galerie-_1_.jpg" title=""><img alt="Sprachschule EC San Diego 2" border="0" height="80" src="typo3temp/pics/EC_San_Diego_Galerie-_1__fd87630014.jpg" title="Sprachschule EC San Diego 2 (Copyright EC San Diego. All rights reserved.)" width="80"/></a>, <a class="lightbox" href="fileadmin/user_upload/images/Sprachen/Englisch/USA/San_Diego/San_Diego_EC/EC_San_Diego_Galerie-_10_.jpg" title=""><img alt="Sprachschule EC San Diego 3" border="0" height="80" src="typo3temp/pics/EC_San_Diego_Galerie-_10__a8ed60c277.jpg" title="Sprachschule EC San Diego 3 (Copyright EC San Diego. All rights reserved.)"`

How can I input in regex to search for multiple exact chars at the beginning?

This one `(?<=\").*?(?=\")` returns everything between `" "` and something like `(?<=\{href="}).*?(?=\")` does not work

Comment: Do you need regex? python should be able to parse the html for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782097/python-is-there-a-built-in-package-to-parse-html-into-dom

Comment: Thanks. I started with the process of learning regex and thats why I want to use it even in cases where other solutions are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the `<content>` in `href="<content>"`, to pattern to match is  `href=\"(.*?)\"` ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/u33SaY/1)) .

With python `re` module, you can do:

```
>>> a= """
... [<a class="lightbox" href="fileadmin/user_upload/images/Sprachen/Englisch/USA/San_Diego/San_Diego_EC/EC_San_Diego_Galerie.jpg" title=""><img alt="Sprachschule EC San Diego" border="0" height="80" src="typo3temp/pics/EC_San_Diego_Galerie_d1def1bf4a.jpg" title="Sprachschule EC San Diego (Copyright EC San Diego. All rights reserved.)" width="80"/></a>, <a class="lightbox" href="fileadmin/user_upload/images/Sprachen/Englisch/USA/San_Diego/San_Diego_EC/EC_San_Diego_Galerie-_1_.jpg" title=""><img alt="Sprachschule EC San Diego 2" border="0" height="80" src="typo3temp/pics/EC_San_Diego_Galerie-_1__fd87630014.jpg" title="Sprachschule EC San Diego 2 (Copyright EC San Diego. All rights reserved.)" width="80"/></a>, <a class="lightbox" href="fileadmin/user_upload/images/Sprachen/Englisch/USA/San_Diego/San_Diego_EC/EC_San_Diego_Galerie-_10_.jpg" title=""><img alt="Sprachschule EC San Diego 3" border="0" height="80" src="typo3temp/pics/EC_San_Diego_Galerie-_10__a8ed60c277.jpg" title="Sprachschule EC San Diego 3 (Copyright EC San Diego. All rights reserved.)"
... 
... """
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'href=\"(.*?)\"',a)
['fileadmin/user_upload/images/Sprachen/Englisch/USA/San_Diego/San_Diego_EC/EC_San_Diego_Galerie.jpg', 'fileadmin/user_upload/images/Sprachen/Englisch/USA/San_Diego/San_Diego_EC/EC_San_Diego_Galerie-_1_.jpg', 'fileadmin/user_upload/images/Sprachen/Englisch/USA/San_Diego/San_Diego_EC/EC_San_Diego_Galerie-_10_.jpg']
>>>
```

Hope this helps.