# Replace string between two delimiters in html

Tags: python, html, python-re

How can I replace some string located between the delimiters **href=""** ?

```
<td><a href="https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uI1n" target="_blank">https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uI1n</a></td>
    </tr>
```

I want to replace this:

```
href="https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uI1n"
```

with this:

```
href="LINK"
```

Comment: What code have you written in an attempt to do this? Can you share it here as a [mre], per guidance on [ask]? Where are you getting stuck? We aren't going to write your code for you, but we can assist if you can demonstrate a good-faith bare-minimum attempt at resolving this on your own before posting here. Why have you elected to use [tag:re] for this when it's widely accepted that [RegExp is not a good solution for parsing (X)HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) due to the extensive edge cases you'll have to account for.

Comment: You tagged this with `re` but I think you should use a HTML Library like BeautifulSoup, rather than trying to do this from scratch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782097/is-there-a-built-in-package-to-parse-html-into-dom

Comment: I am not scraping anything from web. I am generating an email body and filling it with data from a dataframe. When I generate the HTML code with df.to_html() it is shown like this with the whole link in the mail, not being readable for the user

Comment: @alb Who said you were scraping anything from the web...? "*it is shown like this with the whole link in the mail, not being readable for the user*" You haven't stated what you *expect* or desire instead, nor what code you've written (as a [mre]) to either (a) generate this e-mail in the first place, or (b) resolve the issue you describe. Please edit your question to include this and all pertinent debugging/contextual information as prescribed by [ask]. It's very difficult to answer this question as it currently stands.

Comment: And don't you mean you want to change `<a href="https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uI1n" target="_blank">https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uI1n</a>` to 
`<a href="https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uI1n" target="_blank">LINK</a>` otherwise it makes no sense

Comment: @esqew ***I*** asked if he was scraping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty way, you could use re.sub() to match the 'href' tag and replace it with your own:

```
import re
html = """<td><a href="https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uI1n" target="_blank">https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uI1n</a></td>
    </tr>"""
re.sub('">.*<\/a>', '">LINK<\/a>" ' , html)
```

Output:

```
'<td><a href="LINK" target="_blank">https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uI1n</a></td>\n    </tr>'
```

But remember that parsing HTML with regular expressions is not recommended, as it can have many edge cases. I would only use this for a quick and dirty way when I absolutely know how my input HTML is structured. For a more professional approach, you should look into HTML parsers (e.g. 'beautifulsoup').

Comment: thanks for your answer, but as @mplungjan stated, I'd have to replace the other part of the string to rename the hyperlink. So the part after <a> is closed. How it would be?

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect what you wanted to do.

Comment: @alb see the changes.

Comment: thanks it worked!